# ng-repeat with nested ng-repeat between parent data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array of objects with a players array.  I'd like to display the info in a table row, but with the nested array's values in the middle of the row.  I get all the info except the last column.  It comes up blank telling me it's an invalid key.

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-striped"ng-show="vm.registrations.length > 0">
    <thead>
        <td>Day</td>
        <td>Field</td>
        <td>Event</td>
        <td colspan="4">Players</td>
        <td>Status</td>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="event in vm.registrations" >
        <td>{{event.day}}</td>
        <td>{{event.field | uppercase }}</td>
        <td>{{event.event}}</td>
        <td colspan="4" ng-if="event.numplayers == 2">
            <span ng-repeat="player in event.players">
              <span>{{player.first}} {{player.last}}</span>
              <span ng-show="$last">, </span>
            </span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span class="label label-sucess" ng-if="{{event.active}} == true">ACTIVE</span>
            <span class="label label-danger" ng-if="{{event.active}} == false">Canceled</span>
        </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Data should appear like (but the last column is blank, except the header):

```
Day     Field     Event      Players     Status
Sat     MAIN      Mens B     Bob, John   Active
Sun     COED      COED A     Bob, Mary   Canceled
```

This is what I get:

```
Day     Field     Event      Players     Status
Sat     MAIN      Mens B     Bob, John   
Sun     COED      COED A     Bob, Mary
```

How do I get back to the parent ng-repeat to finish the display?

Comment: `ng-if="event.active"`; `ng-if="!event.active"`. Your thread is invalid: it should contain a tr. This tr should contain th, not td. And your colspan="4" are useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

typo here

```
 <span ng-show"$last">
```

you forgot the equals

```
 <span ng-show="$last">
```

that's why you're not seeing the last element of your ng-repeat

Comment: Thanks.  I noticed and corrected that part so the players show correctly but still can't get the status to show up in that pesky last column.

Comment: mm..i've just checked your code, the interpolation inside the ng-if in the last column is not needed ng-if="{{event.active}} == 2, try removing the curly braces and use the strict equality (triple equals).  ng-if="event.active === 2" ...